# python string replacing with re module

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a way to replace a string that can contain any type of characters but with 2 rules:

- This string must not be contained between opening and closing quotes or double quotes.
- It must not be directly preceded or followed by an
  alphanumeric character or an underscore.

For example:

```
myStringToBeReplaced = "any type* of (h@ra[ters –"

mySourceString = """
a = any type* of (h@ra[ters –*2
print "The value of any type* of (h@ra[ters – is: ",any type* of (h@ra[ters –, " and it's like this !"
b  = any type* of (h@ra[ters –With alpha numeric close to it
"""

myReplacementString = "HELLO"

theResultShouldBe ="""
a = HELLO*2
print "The value of any type* of (h@ra[ters – is: ", HELLO, " and it's like this !"
b  = any type* of (h@ra[ters –With alpha numeric close to it
"""
```

Thanks a lot

JD

First attempt with simpler strings for the moment :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: latin1 -*-
import re

myStringToBeReplaced = "anytypeof(h@ra[ters"

mySourceString = """
a = anytypeof(h@ra[ters*2
print "anytypeof(h@ra[ters is:", anytypeof(h@ra[ters , " and it's like this !"
b  = anytypeof(h@ra[tersWith alpha numeric close to it
"""

myReplacementString = "HELLO"

myescape = re.escape(myStringToBeReplaced)

pattern = "(?<!\"|')" + myescape + "(?!\"|')" 

result = re.sub(pattern, myReplacementString, mySourceString)

print result
```

This gives :

```
a = HELLO*2
print "anytypeof(h@ra[ters is:", HELLO , " and it's like this !"
b  = HELLOWith alpha numeric close to it
```

Comment: `This string must not be contained between opening and closing parentheses` But your sample input is inside double quotes not inside parentheses

Comment: if you know exactly which part of the string you want to replace, you can just use the `.replace()` method for the string

Comment: Regex is pretty bad at telling what is and isn't within quotes, parens etc. when there may be multiple such instances around.

Comment: @anubhava: you are right, I made a mistake for the parentheses, I'll edit my post

Comment: I'm trying but I have not succeeded for the moment...

Comment: That is fine. You can show your failed attempt also in question to motivate people to solve your complex problem.

Comment: See http://rextester.com/FCGP22274 - do you need this?

Comment: This is absolutely what I was looking for. Thanks a lot @WiktorStribiżew and the others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your issue, you need to match single- or double quoted strings while capturing them into a group, and then match the search string you need using non-ambiguous `(?<!\w)` / `(?!\w)` word boundaries (as your search terms may start/end with non-word chars, you cannot use `\b`):

```
import re

myStringToBeReplaced = "anytypeof(h@ra[ters"

mySourceString = """
a = anytypeof(h@ra[ters*2
print "anytypeof(h@ra[ters is:", anytypeof(h@ra[ters , " and it's like this !"
b  = anytypeof(h@ra[tersWith alpha numeric close to it
"""

def myReplacementString(m):
    if m.group(1):
        return m.group(1)
    else:
        return "HELLO"

myescape = re.escape(myStringToBeReplaced)
pattern = r'''('[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")|(?<!\w){}(?!\w)'''.format(myescape)
result = re.sub(pattern, myReplacementString, mySourceString)
print result
```

See the [Python demo](http://rextester.com/BMG44522)

**Details**

- `('[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")` - either of the two:

  - `'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'` - a single-quoted C string literal
  - `|`
  - `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"` - a double-quoted string literal
- `|` - or
- `(?<!\w)` -  no word char allowed before the search term
- `{}` - (an escaped search term)
- `(?!\w)` - no word char is allowed after the search term.

Note that `myReplacementString` is now a *method* that will be passed a match data object inside `re.sub` (as the second argument). The match data object is checked there, if Group 1 matched, its value is returned, otherwise, the new string is returned, that will be used to replace the whole match.